# ImageDifference. Is there an ImageSame, or how would one do that?

Tags: functions, image-processing

Is there an inverse to ImageDifference? What in two images are the same?

Comment: Something like `With[{mask = Binarize[ImageDifference[##]]},
   ImageSubtract[#, mask]] & @@ {pic1, pic2}`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Would this work for you: `ImageAdd[img1, Binarize@ImageDifference[img1, img2]]`?

Comment: @Kuba, seems like we are the only active people at a gloomy sunday afternoon :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar Dinner time across Europe, America is aspleep :) I have to study, maybe I should cut off the wire...

Comment: @kuba hey, we're not asleep, just lurking until the coffee kicks in.

Comment: @Kuba and @IstvánZachar - adding `ImageDifference`'s and the required `ImageSame`'s result exactly should restore pic1?

Comment: @UDB I suppose such function on both the same picutures should result with nontouched picture. But this is the qestion to OP.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageDifference`, like many of the image processing commands, calculates on a pixel-by-pixel basis. For instance, `ImageAdd[a,b]` adds each pixel of image `a` to the corresponding pixel of image `b`. `ImageSubtract[a,b]` subtracts each pixel of image `b` from the corresponding pixel of image `a`. In an image in Mathematica, all the pixels lie in the range of 0 to 1, so both `ImageAdd` and `ImageSubtract` can end up with pixels out of range, which will be displayed as either black (if less than zero) or white (if greater than 1). `ImageDifference` does basically the same thing as `ImageSubtract` except that it takes the absolute value of the difference (hence gives Abs(a-b)) for each of the corresponding pixels in images `a` and `b`.

If what you want is to test whether two images are the same, then you can use the standard command SameQ[a,b] which returns True if the two are the same and False if they are different.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in function that can tell where two images have the same pixels, but it's not hard to build one:

```
imageSame[image1_, image2_] := 
    Image[ImageApply[Boole@TrueQ[#1 == #2] &, {image1, image2}], "Bit"]
```

Note that this `imageSame` returns a binary image, whereas `ImageDifference` returns an image with as many channels as the input.